# Siteground Laravel 500 internal server error ajax randomly

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, http-status-code-500

My website is built in laravel 5.4 and hosted on Siteground. The website was working fine before. But now I am randomly getting 500 internal server errors on some ajax request.

Sample code:

```
  var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    var postdata = {
        '_token': csrf_token
    };
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: postdata,
        success: function(data) {

        },
        error: function(data) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: 500 internel server comes when somthing is wrong with your controller. or where you fire ajax request. so please update the controller data

Comment: M.Idrish - this ajax request working randomly. Ajax return HTML as data.

Comment: its possible on data sometimes it not workng because you get data which is not avaliable so example you get information of user with the help of pivot table but not avliable so it throws an error

Comment: simple and easy way make condittion if your response has no data so print some default message so it doesnot throw error or store some default value in response too

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, randomly, in my AJAX requests, the env() function did not work.

That causes 500 errors because the application can't get config variables and i just got a message: `500 Server Error`. Since i replaced the env() calls in my config files, all works fine.

So for exemple in config/app.php, this not work:

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY'),
```

But this works

```
'key' => 'MY_APP_KEY_HARDCODED',
```

Now the trick is to find why env() does not work sometimes...

I discovered the reason thanks to laravel debugbar: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Answer (score 0):

In your .env file put quotes around strings that contain colon

```
APP_KEY="base64:M58ibHSfog9dfg90dfgdfj"
```

This solved the issue for me on Hostinger